# How to figure out what is auto-mounting external drives

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mount, automounting

A long long time ago I apparently installed something that automounts removable drives to the `/media` directory. Now I can't figure out how to unmount stuff anymore. `sudo umount` on the correct `/dev` file doesn't seems to have any effect. I also checked `/etc/fstab` and these drives are not listed. I even went through the list of automounting software on the Arch wiki, and I couldn't find any of them on my system.

Is there a way to figure out what is mounting these drives and also how to unmount them? I'm not sure where I would even start debugging this.

I'm using Arch Linux (btw), and i3, if that matters:

```
Linux 5.13.6-arch1-1
```

**Edit:** requested info:

```
> lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0     1G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 445.9G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 238.5G  0 part /media/AEA2D0BEA2D08C69
sdc      8:32   0 596.2G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 596.2G  0 part /media/d8ee19f6-cb8b-4f23-acd0-91cbee055d69
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part /media/DISK
```

All the drives mounted to `/media` are problematic. `/dev/sdd` is a removable hard drive, so lets focus on that.

```
> mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8148076k,nr_inodes=2037019,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=16741)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,nr_inodes=409600,inode64)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/AEA2D0BEA2D08C69 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=ldm)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/d8ee19f6-cb8b-4f23-acd0-91cbee055d69 type ext4 (rw,relatime,uhelper=ldm)
/dev/sdd1 on /media/DISK type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=ldm)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1631576k,nr_inodes=407894,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Given the last line, it looks like I do have something related to `gvfs` installed.

```
> sudo umount /dev/sdd1
> lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0     1G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 445.9G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 238.5G  0 part /media/AEA2D0BEA2D08C69
sdc      8:32   0 596.2G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 596.2G  0 part /media/d8ee19f6-cb8b-4f23-acd0-91cbee055d69
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part /media/DISK
```

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? I use XFCE, which (by default) will auto-mount removable media.

Comment: I'm using bare bones i3

Comment: Do you have any **gvfs** packages installed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) the output of `mount` including the line describing these mounted drives and ii) any output of the `sudo umount` command. Were there no errors? Did you also try `sudo umount /media/whatever` to unmount the mount point? gvfs and udev seem like the most likely culprits.

Comment: @terdon done. the `umount` on `/media` behaves the same way @ajgringo619 looks like I do have gvfs installed (confirmed by `pacman`, it was installed along the `gnome` package I no longer use). Looks like there's also a systemd service running related to gvfs. I did a little bit of research on it and I couldn't find anything explaining the `umount` behavior or the proper way to unmount stuff with gvfs.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with **gvfs**. With XFCE, this is all done via the **xfce4-settings-editor**. Does **i3** have anything close to this?